# create / generate migration with nestjs error

Tags: javascript, node.js, migration, nestjs

I followed the tutorial on typeorm https://typeorm.io/using-cli#create-a-new-migration

I added `"typeorm": "NODE_ENV=development typeorm-ts-node-esm"` into my `package.json`

in `ormconfig.js` I have

```
const dbConfig = {
  synchronize: false,
  migrations: ['migrations/*.js'],
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: './src/migrations',
  },
};

switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  case 'development':
    Object.assign(dbConfig, {
      type: 'sqlite',
      database: 'db.sqlite',
      entities: ['**/*.entity.js'],
    });
    break;
  case 'test':
    Object.assign(dbConfig, {
      type: 'sqlite',
      database: 'test.sqlite',
      entities: ['**/*.entity.ts'],
    });
    break;
  case 'production':
    break;
  default:
    throw new Error('unknown environment');
}

module.exports = dbConfig;
```

when I try to run `yarn typeorm migration:create -n UserMigration` this is returned

```
$ NODE_ENV=development typeorm-ts-node-esm migration:create -n UserMigration
typeorm-ts-node-esm migration:create <path>

Creates a new migration file.

Options:
  -h, --help       Show help                                           [boolean]
  -o, --outputJs   Generate a migration file on Javascript instead of Typescript
                                                      [boolean] [default: false]
  -t, --timestamp  Custom timestamp for the migration name
                                                       [number] [default: false]
  -v, --version    Show version number                                 [boolean]

Not enough non-option arguments: got 0, need at least 1
Done in 0.48s.
```

I see it's saying I need to add `<path>` to generate the file, but I thought in the `cli` config that sets the default path?

If I ran `yarn typeorm migration:create ./src/migrations/UserMigration -o` and this works as expected.

P.S.

Not sure if it's some documentation error or I am just not sure how to set it up.
[common-data-source-options](https://typeorm.io/data-source-options#common-data-source-options) and I don't see `cli.migrationsDir` as one of the options but in this [data-source-options-example](https://typeorm.io/data-source-options#data-source-options-example) is different.

Thank you in advance for letting me know where I might have setup wrong.

Answer (score 0):

i use this command to generate migration file

```
yarn run typeorm migration:generate -d ./ormconfig src/db/migrations/file-name-without-extension
```

generate migration file with custom name, using **.sh** file

[image]

package script

```
"migration:generate": "bash ./migrate.sh",
```

use this command to generate migration file with a custom name

```
yarn migration:generate file-name-without-extension
```

hope helpful for you